# How to prevent receiving NaN values from excel files in a multilevel index table using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I'm using pandas dataframe to parse some data from a list of excel files, which I intend to move to some excel templates I have for further analysis. Here's an example of what one of the tables look like:[image: tables]

Notice how there are two levels of columns to go through to access the specific data (Westbound & Right, Northbound & Thru, Southbound & Thru). I created a code that parses the data and stores them into different datasets:

df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=worksheet_name, skiprows = 9 , header = [0, 1])

```
    df = df.set_index(df.columns[0], drop = True)
    
    df.index.names = ['Start Time']

    # Convert 'Start Time' to datetime format
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = "%H:%M").strftime("%H:%M")

    # Find the index of the second occurrence of '12:00'
    second_12_index = df.index.to_list().index('12:00', df.index.to_list().index('12:00') + 1)

    # Separate datasets based on 'second_12_index'
    df_weekday = df.iloc[:second_12_index]
    df_saturday = df.iloc[second_12_index:]
    
    # Iterate through compass directions
    for compass_dir in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
        # Get the corresponding traffic movement in the cell directly underneath
        traffic_moves = df.loc[:, (compass_dir, slice(None))].columns.get_level_values(1).unique()
        
        # Iterate through each traffic movement
        for traffic_move in traffic_moves:
        # Iterate through time periods
            for period_name, period in time_periods.items():
                start_time = period['start']
                end_time = period['end']

                # Determine which dataset to apply based on time period
                if period_name in ['Sat', 'Sat Night']:
                    selected_data = df_saturday
                else:
                    selected_data = df_weekday

                # Find the row indices where the time period matches
                time_indices = [i for i, time in enumerate(selected_data.index) if start_time <= datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M").time() <= end_time]

                # Access the DataFrame using the time indices and the specified columns
                fin_data = selected_data.loc[selected_data.index[time_indices], (compass_dir, traffic_move)]
                key = (period_name, compass_dir, traffic_move)
                fin_data_dict[key] = fin_data
                print(fin_data)
```

This works as intended, and categorizes the datasets. The issue arises, however, when dealing with tables such as these:[image: these]

Although the code is able to parse through the different column combinations (Northbound & Thru, Northbound & Right), it returns NaN values as the output:

```
Start Time
19:00   NaN
19:15   NaN
19:30   NaN
19:45   NaN
Name: (Northbound, Thru), dtype: float64
Start Time
07:00   NaN
07:15   NaN
07:30   NaN
07:45   NaN
08:00   NaN
08:15   NaN
08:30   NaN
08:45   NaN
09:00   NaN
09:15   NaN
09:30   NaN
09:45   NaN
Name: (Northbound, Right), dtype: float64
```

For whatever reason, this only applies to tables that has somewhat more complicated multi level indices and only to cells that has formulas applied to them (not actual values/ numbers in the cells. I found that "Refresh All" on excel can restore the data, but it only return 0 values for me for those tables. Why exactly is this happening? And how do I fix it?

Comment: What I do with merged cell headers is simply skip the lines. So in your case use row 11 as headers. You can modify the name with the content from 9 and 10 later on, if you want.